# Comment traduire l'usage de « one » comme pronom indéfini ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, pronoms

On trouve souvent dans les définitions des dictionnaires anglais *one* employé comme substitut d'une personne indéfinie, e.g.

> *There is no need to constantly seek one's approval*

Que je comprends

> Il n'y a pas de besoin de rechercher en permanence l'attention des autres (de quelqu'un d'autre)

Dans ce genre de cas, on peut le traduire par *quelqu'un*, *un autre*.
Mais dans ls cas où ce *one* désigne le sujet du verbe, comme dans

> [To raise one's hand](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wiktionary/en/wiki/raise_one%27s_hand) : (idiomatic) To volunteer.

Où *one's* est censé être remplacé par *my* dans « *I raise my hand* », *your* dans « *You raise your hand* » ... Comment traduire *one* ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Lorsqu'il est sujet, *one* correspond plus ou moins à *on* (même si une traduction littérale n'est pas toujours souhaitable). Pour une fois, on retire le `e` final pour traduire de l'anglais au français.

Lorsqu'il est complément, dans le cas qui t'intéresse, *one* est un [pronom réfléchi](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pronom_r%C3%A9fl%C3%A9chi).

> *To raise one's hand* = (lit.) lever sa main

Au passage, dans le cas non réfléchi, on utilise plutôt *someone* que *one*.

Comment: D'accord avec le reste, mais pour le cas de "raise one's hand", je pense que la traduction équivalente serait "lever la main" (même si "lever sa main" est correcte, c'est moins idiomatique)

Comment: @Dave D'où mon indication « (lit.) ». Tu penses que je devrais écrire en toutes lettres « littéralement » ?

Comment: non, je pense que la signification de "(lit.)" est claire... mais même en y réfléchissant, je ne sais pas si c'est le terme idéal. Disons que l'exemple est juste problématique. D'autant plus que l'usage qui en est fait (en anglais comme en français) n'est pas réfléchi, mais possessif, je pense. "to kill oneself"/"se tuer" serait un usage réfléchi.

Answer (score 3):

C'est une troisième personne du singulier, dans ce cas, tout simplement. Pour citer le *New Oxford American Dictionary* :

> **one**
>   3 [third person singular] used to refer to any person as representing people in general: *one must admire him for his willingness*.
>   • referring to the speaker as representing people in general: *one gets the impression that he is ahead*.
>
> *One* is used as a pronoun to mean ‘anyone’ or ‘me and people in general,’ as in: *one must try one's best*. In modern English, it is generally used only in formal and written contexts. In informal and spoken contexts, the normal alternative is you, as in: *you must try your best*.

Donc, selon le cas, on traduira *one* par le pronom indéfini *on*, le pronom réfléchi *se*, le pronom possessif *son* (ou *sa*, ou *ses*). Exemples :

> to raise one's game — élever son niveau de jeu
>   to raise one's hand — lever sa main (même si on dirait plutôt « lever *la* main »)
>   one another — l'un l'autre
>   one's bark is worse than one's bite — il aboie beaucoup mais ne mord pas

On peut également utiliser, dans certains cas, des traductions plus universalistes, comme « l'homme » :

> one cannot live by bread alone — l'homme ne se nourrit pas seulement de pain